# Tkinter: set a color for points selected by the user

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an image saved as `image.png`. The workflow of my task is this:

1. Load image in Tkinter along with a "select two points" button below the image
2. The user left-clicks with the mouse twice on two points of the image
3. **When he selects the first point, that specific point gets highlighted (say in red, or whichever color); then he selects the second point and also this second point gets highlighted**
4. The (x,y) coordinates of the two points are stored in global variables and will be later used
5. Once the user has selected two points, a second "Done!" button appears. When this button is clicked the GUI closes. N.B I would like the two points to remain highlighted until the user clicks the closing button so that he has an idea of where he/she clicked

I managed to solve all steps, except **step 3**. The most similar thing that I found is to create a rectangle with `canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1,fill="red")`, but first I would prefer a circle and second I don't manage to link the `canvas` to my `Label`

Any help would be appreciated :D

here is my code so far:

```
root = Tk()  # create a window

frame = Frame(root)  # define upper frame
middleframe = Frame(root)  # define middle frame
exitFrame = Frame(root)  # define exit frame
frame.pack()  # pack the frame
middleframe.pack()  # pack the subframe
exitFrame.pack(side = 'bottom')  # pack the exit frame

# function that closes the GUI
def close_window(): 
    root.destroy()

# load the image
img = PhotoImage(file="image.png")  # save the image
panel = Label(frame, image=img)  # display the image as a label
panel.grid(row=0, column=0)  # pack the image

# make the user select some points
global x_Coordinates  # initialize empty list for storing x-axis coordinates
global y_Coordinates  # initialize empty list for storing y-axis coordinates
x_Coordinates = []
y_Coordinates = []

clicks = 0
def countClicks():
  global clicks # this will use the variable to count
  clicks = clicks + 1  # increment "clicks"
  if clicks == 2: # if the user has selected 2 points, add a button that closes the window
      exit_button = Button(exitFrame, state = "normal", text = "Done!", command = close_window)  # link the closing function to the button
      exit_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)  # set button position with "grid"        
pass

def selectPoints():  # function called when user clicks the button "select two points"
    panel.bind("<Button 1>", saveCoordinates)  #  link the function to the left-mouse-click event
    exit_button = Button (exitFrame, state = "disabled", text = "Done!", command = close_window)  # link closing function to the button
    exit_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)  # set button position with "grid"
    button_select_points.config(state = "disabled") # switch button state to "disabled"

def saveCoordinates(event): # function called when left-mouse-button is clicked   
    x_coordinate = event.x  # save x and y coordinates selected by the user
    y_coordinate = event.y
    x_Coordinates.append(x_coordinate)  # append to external list
    y_Coordinates.append(y_coordinate)  # append to external list
    countClicks()  # invoke function "countClicks"

button_select_points = Button(middleframe, text = "select two points", command = selectPoints)  # insert button and link it to "selectPoints"
button_select_points.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)  # set button position with "grid"

root.mainloop()  # keep the GUI open
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this with the image being displayed by a Label.  You need it in a Canvas instead, to which you can also add whatever point markers you want.

Comment: @jasonharper: you can do it in a label. The PhotoImage class has methods that let you set the color of a pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to do more than set a few pixels, it would probably be easier for you to instead use a `Canvas` widget, which has some higher-level drawing primitives (e.g. rectangles and ovals).

(Here's some fairly comprehensive Tkinter documentation about [`Canvas`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190510131423id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) widgets.)

Below is your code with modifications to do this (plus a few others to make it more readable by following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines and with the removal of some things I thought were unnecessary and/or too redundant).

It defines a new helper function named `create_circle()` to simplify calls the more-general `Canvas` widget's `create_oval()` method. This is now called in your `saveCoordinates()` function (which is now what's bound to the `"<Button 1>"` event of the new `Canvas` object instead of the `Label` you were using).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()  # create a window

frame = Frame(root)  # define upper frame
middleframe = Frame(root)  # define middle frame
exitFrame = Frame(root)  # define exit frame
frame.pack()  # pack the frame
middleframe.pack()  # pack the subframe
exitFrame.pack(side='bottom')  # pack the exit frame

# function that closes the GUI
def close_window():
    root.destroy()

img = PhotoImage(file="myimage.png")  # load the image
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=img.width(), height=img.height(), borderwidth=0)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)

# make the user select some points
x_Coordinates = []  # list for storing x-axis coordinates
y_Coordinates = []  # list for storing y-axis coordinates
clicks = 0

def create_circle(canvas, x, y, radius, **kwargs):
    return canvas.create_oval(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, **kwargs)

def countClicks():
    global clicks

    clicks += 1
    # if the user has selected 2 points, add a button that closes the window
    if clicks == 2:
        # link the closing function to the button
        exit_button = Button(exitFrame, state="normal", text="Done!",
                             command=close_window)
        exit_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)  # set button position with "grid"

def selectPoints():  # function called when user clicks the button "select two points"
    # link the function to the left-mouse-click event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>", saveCoordinates)
    # link closing function to the button
    exit_button = Button (exitFrame, state="disabled", text="Done!",
                          command=close_window)
    exit_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)  # set button position with "grid"
    button_select_points.config(state="disabled") # switch button state to "disabled"

def saveCoordinates(event): # function called when left-mouse-button is clicked
    x_coordinate = event.x  # save x and y coordinates selected by the user
    y_coordinate = event.y
    x_Coordinates.append(x_coordinate)
    y_Coordinates.append(y_coordinate)
    # Display a small dot showing position of point.
    create_circle(canvas, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, radius=3, fill='red')
    countClicks()

# insert button and link it to "selectPoints"
button_select_points = Button(middleframe, text="select two points",
                              command=selectPoints)
button_select_points.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

root.mainloop()  # keep the GUI open
```

Comment: Set individual pixels in a PhotoImage that is on a label. You can't draw other things on top, however.

Comment: @Bryan: I'll take your word for that (as usual, that's not well documented—like much of tkinter). Besides, personally I'd prefer to use the higher-level drawing methods a `Canvas` provides than by setting individual pixels to do this (unless of course `PhotoImage`'s have those, too).

Comment: It's documented about as well as anything else in tkinter :-\. It's fully documented in the tcl/tk documentation, and is in the `PhotoImage` docstring, as well as on a few other websites.

Comment: I agree that a canvas is probably a better choice. I just think the first sentence of the answer is misleading when it says it can't be done on a label.

Comment: @Bryan: Agreed—see new first sentence. Will also check some of those references (thanks).

Comment: Thanks @martineau, this also works perfectly. I just had to modify image width and height to 512x512 since 300x300 were too small. See edit.
Thank you guys again!

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the clarification @martineau!

Comment: @Tommaso: Thanks again. Note that in response to your attempted change, I've modified my answer a bit so it will now automatically create the right-size `Canvas`.

Answer (score 2):

> 3. When he selects the first point, that specific point gets highlighted (say in red, or whichever color); then he selects the second point and also this second point gets highlighted
>
> I managed to solve all steps, except step 3

The `PhotoImage` class has methods for setting the color of a pixel. For example, to set the pixel at the x/y of the event to red, do this:

```
img.put(("red",), to=(event.x, event.y))
```

Since a single pixel is really hard to see, you can draw a small 3x3 rectangle centered around the point fairly easily. The following example puts the color red to the pixels in a square from `event.x-1, event.y-1` to `event.x+1, event.y+1`:

```
img.put(("red",), to=(event.x-1, event.y-1, event.x+1, event.y+1))
```

---

The first argument to the `put` method is a list of colors, which can either be known color names or rgb specifications (eg: `#ff0000` for red, etc). If here is not enough data to fill the specified region, the provided data will be tiled.

The `to` argument specifies either a single x/y coordinate or two x/y coordinates that define a rectangular region.